# Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported with Date

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I am trying to index beginning of the year prices for the following stocks using the
following daterange:

```
dtr = pd.date_range(start='2005-01-01',end='2020-01-01',freq='Y').date
```

for the dataframe

```
                  ECL         ED        EFX        EMN        EMR       EQIX  
Date                                                                           
2004-12-31  29.188265  21.974245  23.909544  14.893614  21.059916  35.216614   
2005-01-03  28.747896  21.748219  24.386028  14.782673  20.639318  35.612129   
2005-01-04  28.382326  21.682922  23.535154  13.464359  20.398973  34.928238   
2005-01-05  28.108135  21.446857  23.679798  13.314729  20.215719  34.203125   
2005-01-06  28.191223  21.471962  23.484104  13.593354  20.347906  34.491512   
2005-01-07  28.025047  21.532238  23.381994  13.482425  20.167650  34.120735   
2005-01-10  28.274302  21.808495  23.288401  13.510804  20.215719  34.788147   
2005-01-11  28.041676  21.768312  23.237345  13.392123  20.380947  34.417366   
2005-01-12  27.966890  21.838623  23.271381  13.392123  20.308853  34.598637   
2005-01-13  27.617929  21.843651  23.169277  13.294093  20.065500  33.815876
```

In the past

```
df.loc[dtr]
```

used to solve my problem, however in newer versions of pandas it throws the error:

KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%27)

Which is the 'new' correct way to go about it?

Comment: As it suggests `df.reindex(dtr)`? Not entirely sure what you expect the output to be, you have missing keys so should those rows be all `NaN` or dropped entirely? The biggest annoyance can be upcasting due to `NaN`.